# What is the best way to load a massive amount of data into PostgreSQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, copy, loading

I want to load a massive amount of data into PostgreSQL. Do you know any other "tricks" apart from the ones mentioned in the PostgreSQL's documentation?

What have I done up to now?

1) set the following parameters in postgresql.conf (for 64 GB of RAM):

```
    shared_buffers = 26GB 
    work_mem=40GB
    maintenance_work_mem = 10GB       #  min 1MB default: 16 MB
    effective_cache_size = 48GB
    max_wal_senders = 0     # max number of walsender processes
    wal_level = minimal         # minimal, archive, or hot_standby
    synchronous_commit = off # apply when your system only load data (if there are other updates from clients it can result in data loss!)
    archive_mode = off      # allows archiving to be done
    autovacuum = off            # Enable autovacuum subprocess?  'on'
    checkpoint_segments = 256       # in logfile segments, min 1, 16MB each; default = 3; 256 = write every 4 GB
    checkpoint_timeout = 30min         # range 30s-1h, default = 5min
    checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9  # checkpoint target duration, 0.0 - 1.0
    checkpoint_warning = 0              # 0 disables, default = 30s
```

2) transactions (disabled autocommit) + set isolation level (the lowest possible: repeatable read) I create a new table and load data into it in the same transaction.

3) set `COPY` commands to run a single transaction (supposedly it is the fastest approach to `COPY` data)

5) disabled autovacuum (will not regenerate statistics after new 50 rows added)

6) `FREEZE COPY FREEZE` does not speed up the import itself but makes operations after the import faster.

Do you have any other recommendations or maybe you do not agree with the aforementioned settings?

Comment: Are you sure you want checkpoint_timeout to fire a checkpoint every 45 seconds? 30 minutes (or something like that) makes more sense to me. But, what is your definition of "massive amount of data" ?

Comment: Now, I load data with sizes ranging from about 1GB to 100GB. Probably, you are right that in this case the checkpoint timeout should be increased. The loading time takes more that 30 min, so I'll try to increase the checkpoint timeout. Thank you.

Comment: By the way, I would not turn auto vacuum off, you can't turn it on without downtime. Or do you run your own scripts to do vacuum and analyze?

Comment: I execute a standard form of VACUUM (which can run in parallel with production database operations) and then run ANALYZE for each table after the whole data loading process.

Comment: effective_cache_size + maintenance_work_mem + shared_buffers := 100GB, which is larger than your physical memory.

Comment: You don't add the numbers in this way because there are some overlaps. For example, the effective_cache_size is an estimate of how much memory is available for disk caching by the operating system and within the database itself, so we can say that the size of the effective_cache_size incorporates the size of shared_buffers.

Comment: I found some other recommendations: Setting effective_cache_size to 1/2 of total memory would be a normal conservative setting, and 3/4 of memory is a more aggressive but still reasonable amount. For shared buffers: it's unlikely you'll find using more than 40% of RAM to work better than a smaller amount. For more write-heavy systems, values from 32 (checkpoint every 512MB) to 256 (every 4GB) are popular nowadays.

Comment: lowering the average write overhead, by increasing the checkpoint_completion_target parameter to its useful maximum of 0.9 (aim to finish by the time 90% of the next checkpoint is here) https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Tuning_Your_PostgreSQL_Server

Comment: When a small amount of data loss is acceptable in return for a large boost in how many updates you can do to the database per second, consider switching synchronous commit off.

For obsolete versions of PostgreSQL, you may find that setting fsync=off speeds up writes on busy systems. However, this is dangerous--a power loss could result in your database getting corrupted and not able to start again.

Answer (score 1):

Do **NOT** use **indexes** except for unique single numeric key.

That doesn't fit with all DB theory we received but testing with heavy loads of data demonstrate it. Here is a result of 100M loads at a time to reach 2 Billions rows in a table, and each time a bunch of various queries on the resulting table. First graphic with 10 gigabit NAS (150MB/s), second with 4 SSD in RAID 0 (R/W @ 2GB/s).

[image: Index use vs sequential - 150MB/s disks]

If you have more than 200 millions row in a table on regular disks, it's faster if you forget indexes. On SSD's, the limit is at 1 billion.

[image: Index use vs sequential - 2 GB/s SSD]

I've done it also with partitions for better results but with PG9.2 it's difficult to benefit from them if you use stored procedures. You also have to take care of writing/reading to only 1 partition at a time. However partitions are the way to go to keep your tables below the 1 Billion row wall. It also helps **a lot** to multiprocess your loads. With SSD, single process let me insert (copy) 18,000 rows/s (with some processing work included). With multiprocessing on 6 CPU, it grows to 80,000 rows/s.

Watch your CPU & IO usage while testing to optimize both.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A rule of thumb says that indexes should be created after data loading (especially for first-time loading). If you can recreate your indexes in parallel and load more that 5% of existing data then it's usually better to drop the indexes before loading (including the "unique key" index). You give the results in rows/sec but this metric is specific for your data, it would be a bit better to report the results in MB/sec or GB/sec. The loading of data in CSV format is heavily CPU bounds and the influence of IO is not that significant.

Comment: How do the stored procedures preclude the loading with partitions enabled?

Comment: What is the 1 Billion row wall? By the way, the tables in PostgreSQL are stored in 1 GB files by default. So, do you load the data and run some queries at the same time? What is the physical size of your data? Do you use any benchmark (e.g. TPC-H or YCSB)? This is a very well known approach, to use as much parallelism as possible for your data loading, the case is how to harness many cores efficiently, it's not a trivial problem.

Comment: a) 1 billion rows wall refers to the number of rows from which it's slower to make a relatively simple query with index than without it (but not as trivial as getting 1 row with numeric primary key), even with fast IO.
b) Stored proc doesn't preclude loading in partitions, it's just difficult to benefit from them if your queries are done inside stored proc, the query plan doesn't reevaluate them so it ends by scanning all partition instead of the one you optimized your query for.

Comment: c) I agree with you my results are dependent of a lot of factors, I made my own benchmark to compare various hardware and configuration solutions a few years ago. d) Number of cores is a balance between CPU% & IO% of utilization. Disabling multi-threading in BIOS was a good start.

Comment: The idea behind these results is to test your processing needs with and without indexes and the result may be rapidly to completely get rid of them when you deal with big tables, not only to redo them after loading.